# Spartacus front-end logging system?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I would like to setup logging system on Spartacus storefront.

Does Spartacus has any default logging system?

For example: `Graylog`?

For example I have timer for some action, and if timer expired, I want to log it to the graylog. Timer in some Angular Service.

Comment: Can you further elaborate what you're trying to achieve? Graylog is used server side afaik, are you looking for consolidated log information on the server, i.e. to monitor the SSR server? Commerce Cloud runs Kibana to this.

Comment: @tobi-or-not-tobi For example I have timer for some action, and if timer expired, I want to log it to the graylog. Timer in some Angular Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We forked https://github.com/dbfannin/ngx-logger and added an OCC endpoint which the logger can submit logs to. The OCC endpoint logs to a logger that is dedicated to the frontend.

Comment: Does this library have possibility to send logs to the remote server as graylog or whatever?

Comment: Yes, it supports POSTing to a configurable URL out of the box but that was not sufficient for us, hence the fork.

Comment: So there is default configuration for logging in Spartacus as I understood from your message? I think we don't need to have fork for it, nothing specific at the moment. Could you please send some link to docs where configure logging on storefront?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. You need to add ngx-logger as a dependency to your project or copy it into your own code base. When that is done, you can add logging to _your_ code, not Spartacus unless you fork it as well.